# Angularjs child cannot update parent variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers:

```
app.controller('mainController',['$scope','$templateCache','$route','$location',function($scope, $templateCache,$route,$location) {

        $scope.clear = function(){
            //console.log("clicked");
            //console.log($route.current.originalPath);
            $( "#ActiveWarning" ).show();
            $templateCache.removeAll();
            $route.reload();
            $location.path( $route.current);
        }
}]);
```

And

```
app.register.controller('settingsController', function ($scope) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btnSubmitAccountSetting").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: 'Your account will be switched to unverified until you verify your account with updated documents.',
                    type: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, update it!',
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function() {
                    console.log("Clicked");
                    $scope.name = "toto";
                    $scope.$parent.name="toto";
                    console.log("all");
                    $scope.$digest();
                    $scope.$parent.name="toto";
                });
        });
    });
});
```

The `settingController` being the child of the `mainController`. The issue is that am not being able to update the `name` variable which I set in the mainController via 
`<data ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="name = '{{$BasicInfo["name"]}}'"/>`

I tried with  `$scope.$parent.name="toto";` but no help. I also tired to add setters in the mainController but that also didnt helped.

Only the variable in the child controller is updating, not the parent controller.

How can i update the name variable in the parent controller from the child controller. which is within the `ng-view` **directive**?

**structure of html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> Dashboard</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini" ng-controller="mainController">
    <data ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="name = 'Kheshav'"/>
    <dava ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="surname = 'Sewnundun'"/>   
<script src="http://maurijob.devlocal/libraries/JS/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maurijob.devlocal/libraries/JS/angularjs/angular-1.4.8.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maurijob.devlocal/libraries/JS/angularjs/angular-1.4.8-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maurijob.devlocal/libraries/MyAngular/app.js"></script>
      <div class="content-wrapper"   ng-view>

    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

Removed jquery in the controller:

```
app.register.controller('settingsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modal = function(){
            swal({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: 'Your account will be switched to unverified until you verify your account with updated documents.',
                    type: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, update it!',
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function() {
                    console.log("Clicked");
                    $scope.name = "toto";
                    $scope.$parent.name="toto";
                    console.log("all");
                    $scope.$digest();
                    $scope.$parent.name="toto";
                });
    }

});
```

Comment: Mixing JQuery and angular is not recommended for this kind of thing.  You should use angular's `ng-click` on the HTML itself instead of using JQuery event handling.  Or some directive.  Otherwise some stuff happens outside angular's knowledge and you'll have to start messing around with `$digest` and `$apply` stuff.

Comment: Ive removed the jquery and used `ng-click=` please check update.

Comment: create a method on parent controller to update value then call this method from child controller supplying the value.like create `$scope.changename = function(newVal) {
    $scope.name = newVal;
  };` then call this from child controller like `$scope.changename('value');`

Comment: @Neel Ive already tried it it didnt worked unfortunately.

Comment: I have strong doubt on your code.Firstly you have messed up jquery by writing document.ready in controller.also I see you are assigning $scope.parent.name two times in controller.also are you saying $scope.parent is not updating parent scope.

Comment: @Neel Thats right the `$scope.parent` is not updating the parent scope. My appology for assigning the `$scope.parent.name` twice it must have been let during the testing. Besides ive corrected the jquery part and used `ng-click=modal()` as ive mentioned in the updated section. Thanks